# TypeError: can't convert Net::HTTPOK into String

Tags: ruby, json, net-http, google-geocoding-api

I'm using `net/http` and `json` to geocode an address using google's Geocoding API. Here is where the error is being thrown:

```
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
result = JSON.parse(response)
```

The response is of class Net::HTTPOK, but I want to access the actual JSON response data (not just the status code).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You want

```
result = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPResponse.html