# how deserialize a json in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I send a http request and get a json for response like below:

```
{"total":"1200.0","used":"35.0","available":1165.0}
```

now I want deserialize this json and show to user in a table like below:

```
total : 1200

used : 35

availabele : 1165
```

I use `JSON.parse(response)`,but I get below error:

```
no implicit conversion of Net::HTTPOK into String
```

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353227/typeerror-cant-convert-nethttpok-into-string

Comment: Always google the error message, you have a better chance of finding a solution.

Comment: I use this link, But question is a bit different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Net::HTTP has responses in `body`. so, Try

```
JSON.parse response.body
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `response.body` as the parameters into the `JSON.parse` method then assign the method to a variable to use elsewhere in your code.

```
parse_res = JSON.parse(res.body)
```